# Cyclotomic Polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ and reduction modulo $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $p$ be prime, and let $\pi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / (p\mathbb Z)$ be the canonical projection $\pi(z) = z + p\mathbb Z$. Define its extension $\pi :  \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z/(p\mathbb Z)[x]$ by applying it to the coefficients.

Let $\Phi_{n, K}$ denote the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial, and let $n$ not divisble by $p$, then I have to show that
$$
 \pi(\Phi_{n, \mathbb Q}) = \Phi_{n, \mathbb Z/ (p\mathbb Z)}.
$$

Let $K$ be a field, and let $L/K$ be a field extension, the set $E_n := \{ a ~:~ a^n = 1 \}$ is the set of the roots of unity, such a root $a$ is called *primitive* if $a^k \ne 1$ for $1 \le k < n$, let $\overline{E}_n$ denote the set of primitive roots. The cyclotomic polynomial is defined to be 
$$
 \Phi_{n,K} := \prod_{e \in \overline{E}_n} (x - e).
$$

Now I looked at the following examples, and found that the above mentioned equality does not hold.

In $\mathbb Z/(5\mathbb z) = \{ 0,1,2,3,4 \}$ with $n = 7$ we have $E_7 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\overline{E}_7 = \emptyset$ (because $x^4 = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z/(5\mathbb Z)$), so 
$$
 \Phi_{7, \mathbb Z / (5\mathbb Z)} = 0
$$
because the product is empty, but
$$
 \Phi_{7, \mathbb Q} = x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1.
$$
So they are not equal?? Furthermore, look at $n = 3$, then $\overline{E}_3 = \{ 2,3\}$, so
$$
 \Phi_{3, \mathbb Z/(5\mathbb Z)} = (x-2)(x-3) = x^2 - 5x + 1 = x^2 + 1
$$
and 
$$
 \Phi_{3, \mathbb Q} = x^2 + x + 1.
$$
So they are not equal again??? So what did I wrong??

Comment: Possibly you are missing the assumption $n \mid p - 1$. Also, I don't think your second example works, as $2^3 \equiv 3^3 \equiv 3 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: yes, I missed an assumption, but it is that $n$ is not divisible by $p$ (and $n \mid p - 1$ is not an assumption according to the exercise).

Comment: I think that it is likely that you are supposed to find the primitive roots in the smallest extension field $L$ of $K$ that contains those primitive roots.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, good guess.

Comment: BTW the value of the empty product is one, not zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is true under the assumption $n \mid p-1$. (**PS** Or, taking **@JyrkiLahtonen**'s guess, you replace $\Bbb{Z}/p \Bbb{Z}$ with its smallest extension containing the roots.)

A possible proof uses induction on $n$ and the inclusion/exclusion principle, starting with
$$
x^n - 1 = \prod_{t \mid n} \Phi_{t, \Bbb{Q}}(x).
$$